# How to implement RabbitMq for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rabbitmq

I'm trying to implement RabbitMQ into my ios project.
First of all, I tried it with `https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc`

However, after several steps and it still didn't work, I got frustrated and switched to this one

`https://github.com/EFEducationFirstMobile/librabbitmq-objc`

It's like pre-support for IOS (`Foundation` insteads of `Cocoa`, ARC supported ...) and I just copied `rabbitmq-c` folder and wapper classes. It builds successfully.

Then I tried to run it with these line of codes:

```
 AMQPConnection *connection = [[AMQPConnection alloc] init];
[connection connectToHost:@"123.45.678.90" onPort:12345];
[connection loginAsUser:@"test" withPassword:@"test" onVHost:@"/"];
AMQPChannel *channel = [connection openChannel];
```

but it throws this error at the second line:

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
>   fcntl$UNIX2003 called from function amqp_open_socket_noblock in image MyApp.

can anybody help me with this error ? thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you trying to run RabbitMQ within your iOS app, or just connect to an instance running elsewhere and perform operations?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using [Objective-C wrapper for librabbitmq-c library](https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc). I am able to connect, create exchange, create queue, bind queue publish message using this library:

**For using in iOS**

**Delete:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

**Use:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

**And if file not found using this:**

```
# import <amqp.h>
```

**Use this:**

```
# import "amqp.h"
```

I hope this will almost solve your problem. You may get some error on uint64 fix it as Xcode suggests you. And it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

bug has been fixed by Dmitry Makarenko (lib's owner)

Answer (score 0):

For a correct answer you can use this for iOS using objective-c, it's a pain but it's doable.

From my own research it seems like there have been a lot of people that have pulled this off, but they are all closed source projects that they will not share source code.

For your question you have to make sure you include the rabbitMQ-c source code in your project along with the wrapper. Take out all of the dealloc stuff that conflicts with ARC or turn ARC off for the wrapper.

And to answer your question, just change the cocoa\cocoa import lines to foundation\foundation.h.

Comment: I know, that what have to be done when implementing `profmaad`'s lib into an IOS project. However, you don't have to do that with `EFEducation`'s one because that lib supports ios.

Answer (score 0):

The really hard to find ready, easy setup library for rabbitmq on iOS platform the problem is with implementation rabbitmq-c, so I try created own implementation wrapper with usage cocoapods. OLRabbitMQ ( https://github.com/open-rnd/OLRabbitMQ) is also wrapper but you can use cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is it possible to set custom header parameters or reply_to while sending a message?